# NHibernate - two lists with same type in same entity

Tags: nhibernate

I have this class which i would like to map:

```
public class Contract
{
        public virtual IList<Right> RightsSystem1 { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Right> RightsSystem2 { get; set; }
}
```

With mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem1).Not.LazyLoad();
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem2).Not.LazyLoad();
```

Where Right is another mapped class which represents certain rights two diffrent systems have (it can be like "*GetPartStockQuantity*" or "*GetOrderStatus*").

The problem im having is that when i add one right to each of the two lists and then getting them with NHibernate both of the lists have two items (which are the two i added seperately).

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both manytomany default to the same table and column names. you need to specify them explicitly:

```
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem1).Table("FooRights").Not.LazyLoad();
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem2).Table("BarRights").Not.LazyLoad();

//or
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem1).ChildKeyColumn("FooRight_id").Not.LazyLoad();
HasManyToMany(c => c.RightsSystem2).ChildKeyColumn("BarRight_id").Not.LazyLoad();
```